# Help in identifying marine specimen?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology, invertebrates

I came across this specimen which I assume belongs toeither the phylum [porifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge) or to the [coelenterata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelenterata).
Can someone please help me identify it?[image][image][image]

The specimen was found in Ayodhya, India.

Comment: Please update your question by including where you found this specimen. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking it is the **skeleton of a colonial large polyp stony coral**. I am not certain, but I suspect a species of the Favia genus. Most likely one of these two species (see links for info and pictures):

- [*Favia lizardensis*](http://www.coralsoftheworld.org/species_factsheets/species_factsheet_summary/favia-lizardensis/)
- [*Favia rosaria*](http://www.coralsoftheworld.org/species_factsheets/species_factsheet_summary/favia-rosaria/)

Comment: Looks quite similar. However, many stony corals appear rather similar when dead. Could you add additional information in support of your answer?